# I wanna get a four digit number within 1-7

Tags: python

I want to get a 4 digit number in python in which each number is less than 8 (1-7). ex. 1576 is acceptable but 2976 is not because 9 is bigger than 7

```
squawk = random.randint(1000, 7777)
```

I have this code but this also gives numbers like 2976
Please help me

Comment: Do you want to find all numbers (e.g., [1000, 1001, ...., ]) or just a random number that satisfies your condition?

Comment: If the digits have to all be 1-7, why is 1000 the minimum and not 1111?

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
num = int(str(random.randint(1,7))+str(random.randint(1,7))+str(random.randint(1,7))+str(random.randint(1,7)))
print(num)
```

Alternate way suggested by @blorgon:

```
int(f"{random.randint(1,7)}{random.randint(1,7)}{random.randint(1,7)}{random.randint(1,7)}")
```

Comment: I'd recommend using an f-string over repeated `str` casting.

Answer (score 3):

In this case you can generate four random numbers and then stick them together:

`squawk = sum(random.randint(1,7)*10**i for i in range(4))`

This will generate each digit independently and scale it to the appropriate column.

Comment: The `sum()` function can take a generator as its argument. No need to put the list into memory first.

Comment: Thanks blorgon, have edited the answer.

Comment: Coolio! I like this over my own answer, since it's all numeric.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try something like this

```
number = ""
for _ in range(4):
    number += str(random.randint(1, 8))

number = int(number)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest solution I can think of:

```
squawk = int(''.join(random.sample('1234567', 4)))
```

Comment: `str.join()` can take a generator as its argument. No need to create a list in memory first.

Comment: ah...right on man! - made that improvement.  Thanks @blorgon!

Comment: You could use `random.sample('1234567'*4, 4)`  and skip the for loop.

Comment: Wow.  I didn't know about `sample`.  Nice. (I don't know why you added the `*4`.  I left if off, obvously).

Comment: @CryptoFool, `random.sample()` selects items *without* replacement.  With only 1 copy of each digit, the code can't generate numbers with repeated digits like `3333`.  The `*4` provides 4 copies of each digit so numbers with up to 4 copies of a digit can be generated.

Answer (score 1):

```
Squawk=oct(random.randint(512,4095))[2:]
```

512 & 4095 are equivalent to 1000 & 7777
This will always give you the desired result. The result might include 0 numbers.